# ObservedObject only passes its default value; not its assigned value. Why?

Tags: combine, observableobject, observedobject

**Scenario:** Attempting to broadcast a variable value via an *ObservableObject*.

**Problem:** I'm only getting the default value; not the *assigned* value.

Here's the origin. 
Button #1 starts a function to get data.

Button #2 retrieves the ObservedObject's revised value

I removed some of the vestigial code to make the presentation simpler:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

    let fontCustom = Font.custom("Noteworthy", size: 23.0)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
        // ...
        // ...
 HStack {
         Button(
              action: {
                  NetworkManager().getCalculatorIDs()
              },
              label: { 
                 Text("1")
              }
         )

        Button(
             action: {
                 self.calculator.calculate("2");
                 print(self.networkManager.calculationID)  // stop and check.                            
             },
             label: { Text("2") }
        )
// ...
// ...
}
}
```

So I tap Button #1 then tap Button #2 to check if the *ObservedObject* has the *generated id value*.

I'm expecting an alphanumeric id value in the print().

Instead, I got the original value:

```
Royal Turkey
(lldb)
```

Here's the ObservableObject:

```
struct CalculationIdentifier: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let tokens: [String]
}

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var calculationID = "Royal Turkey"
    @Published var isAlert = false
    @Published var name = "Ric Lee"

    let calculations = "https://calculator-frontend-challenge.herokuapp.com/Calculations"

    func getCalculatorIDs() {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: calculations)!)
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral

        let task = URLSession(configuration: configuration).dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, _, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([CalculationIdentifier].self, from: data!)
                    if !result.isEmpty {
                        self.calculationID = (result[0] as CalculationIdentifier).id
                        print("Inside do{}. result = \(result)")
                        self.isAlert = true
                    } else {
                        print(#function, "Line:", #line, ": No Result")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

BTW: Here's the *local* console output, the string value of 'id' should have been passed to the host as an *ObservedObject* value:

```
Inside do{}. result = [RicCalculator2.CalculationIdentifier(id: "d3dd3b1e-d9f6-4593-8c85-b8fd3d018383", tokens: [])]
```

So I do have a bona fide id value to send.

Why only the original value? 
What am I missing?

...do I need to do a 'send' or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

> A.    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

and this

> B.      NetworkManager().getCalculatorIDs()

in your code are different objects, ie. you create one object as member, then other object on the stack, which does something, and then ask first object to return something - naturally if returns what it has on initialise.

Probably you assumed in case B

```
self.networkManager.getCalculatorIDs()
```